# How to stop facebook caching temporarily for a page

Tags: facebook, caching

I am currently allowing Facebook to scrape my website and cache data. However, I have certain (temporarily inactive) pages which are being redirected to my homepage. When Facebook scrape these pages, it is getting the info from my homepage OG tags.

When these pages become active, they are no longer redirected to homepage. However, since Facebook has cached the data, whenever someone tries to share these pages, they will see my scraped information on my homepage.

This is an example:

- www.mywebsite.com/page/123 is temporarily redirected to www.mywebsite.com
- Facebook tries to scrape data of www.mywebsite.com/page/123, see that it is being redirected (either 301 or 302) so it cache the data of www.mywebsite.com
- When www.mywebsite.com/page/123 is no longer redirected, Facebook still use the cached data of www.mywebsite.com for www.mywebsite.com/page/123 which causes a lot of confusion.

I am aware of the Facebook debugger tool to clear cache for www.mywebsite.com/page/123 but we have so many pages like this so going through each one of them is very tedious and impractical

Is there a way to tell Facebook NOT to scrape www.mywebsite.com/page/123 until we want it to?

Thanks,

Eddeee

Comment: You can trigger a re-scrape (that will clear the cache) via API, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/using-objects#update If that’s not a satisfactory solution, then you should make sure that Facebook does not get to “see” those URLs until the articles are published in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Cbroe for the idea, I solved this problem by making the unpublished page returning a 404 until it is fully active. This will stop Facebook "seeing" the page and not scraping any information initially.